# How can I put the second rows of a file to form two column with well aligned second column?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a pipe that leads to

```
# myfunctionwithpipe
a1
a2
b1
b2
...
```

And want to have

```
a1.            a2
b1.            b2
...
```

The difference with other threads is that I'd like to have the second column at one specific horizontal distance and perfectly well aligned.

Comment: Are the periods significant? you can separate with tabs simply using `paste - - ` e.g. `myfunctionwithpipe | paste - - ` or use wider 2-column output using `pr` e.g. `myfunctionwithpipe | pr -ta -2`

Comment: 'pr -ta -2' works great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfunctionwithpipe | pr -ta -2
```

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways that you can write some as following:

```
... | xargs -d'\n' -n2
... | paste -sd'\t\n'
... | paste - -
```